# Dagger 2 with ViewModel, Repository, Room and Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, android-room, dagger-2, kotlin-coroutines

I' trying to utilize Dagger 2 in a ViewModel + Respository + Room + Retrofit + Coroutines project written in Kotlin.

Currently each ViewModel initializes required repositories and their dependences by itself like so

```
class HomeViewModel(
    application: Application
) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository: UserRepository =
        UserRepository(
            Webservice.create(),
            AppDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).userDao()
        )
```

I would like to get this simplified to this

```
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: UserRepository
): ViewModel()
```

What I have achieved so far

Created the dagger component and modules

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AppModule::class,
    NetworkModule::class,
    DataModule::class,
    RepositoryModule::class
])
interface AppComponent {
    val webservice: Webservice
    val userRepository: UserRepository
}

@Module
class AppModule(private val app: Application) {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(): Application = app
}

@Module
class DataModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplicationDatabase(app: Application, scope: CoroutineScope) =
        AppDatabase.getDatabase(app, scope)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserDao(db: AppDatabase) = db.userDao()
}

@Module
class NetworkModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideWebservice() = Webservice.create()
}

@Module
class RepositoryModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserRepository(webservice: Webservice, userDao: UserDao) =
        UserRepository(webservice, userDao)
}
```

Got the AppComponent initilized in the application class

```
class App : Application() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent
    }
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appComponent = initDagger(this)
    }
    private fun initDagger(app: App): AppComponent =
        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(AppModule(app))
            .build()
}
```

And now I'm stuck.

**The first question is**: How do I make the ViewModel's inject constructor work?

Originally it was initialized from the HomeFragment like so

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
```

How do I call the initializer now?

**The second question is** a bit harder.

The database constructor requies a Coroutine scope in order to prepopulate it in a background thread during creation. How do I pass in a scope now?

Here is the definition of the database and the callback

```
@Database(
    entities = [User::class],
    version = 1, exportSchema = false
)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context, scope: CoroutineScope): AppDatabase {
            val tempInstance =
                INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    "database"
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(AppDatabaseCallback(scope))
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }

    private class AppDatabaseCallback(
        private val scope: CoroutineScope
    ) : RoomDatabase.Callback() {RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onCreate(db)
            INSTANCE?.let { database ->
                scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    //inserts
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The second question is a bit harder.
>
> The database constructor requies a Coroutine scope in order to prepopulate it in a background thread during creation. How do I pass in a scope now?

It's actually easier, don't pass in a `CoroutineScope`, use the `GlobalScope` for this operation.

> The first question is: How do I make the ViewModel's inject constructor work?

You need to obtain the `Provider<HomeViewModel>` from Dagger, then invoke it inside a `ViewModelProvider.Factory` to create the instance of `HomeViewModel` via the provider registered in the Dagger component.

Alternately, if the Activity has its own subcomponent, then you can use `@BindsInstance` to get the Activity instance into the graph, then move `ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(HomeViewModel::class.java, object: ViewModelProvider.Factory {
   ...
   return homeViewModelProvider.get() as T
   ...
})` into a module of that subcomponent. Then, from that subcomponent, it would be possible to obtain an actual instance of the `HomeViewModel`, and still obtain proper scoping + `onCleared()` callback.

Comment: Thank for the answer. Is it really good practice to use `GlobalScope` in production builds particularly for this case? Can you please provide and example code of how to `obtain the Provider<HomeViewModel> from Dagger, then invoke it inside a ViewModelProvider.Factory`? The activity which holds the HomeFragment does not have its own subcomponents.

Comment: You obtain the Provider just like you would obtain a ViewModel instance from Dagger, except you specify it as `Provider<MyViewModel>` instead of `ViewModel`. If GlobalScope was a liability in all cases, it would not exist.

Comment: Is it the same approach as this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48837581/5360898

Comment: Just wanted to mention that GlobalScope is for sure permitted here, but there are better ways to go about using a GlobalScope by including an error handler, otherwise you will need to supply try catches to all of your GlobalScope coroutine blocks if they can error out.

https://proandroiddev.com/coroutines-snags-6bf6fb53a3d1

Reffering to bottom "Logging Exceptions"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass a coroutine scope just run a coroutine in IO dispacher like:

```
@Database(
entities = [
    Login::class],
version = 1,
exportSchema = false
)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun loginDao(): LoginDao

companion object {

    @Volatile private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

    fun getInstance(app: Application): AppDatabase = INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            INSTANCE ?: buildDatabase(app).also { INSTANCE = it }
        }

    private fun buildDatabase(app: Application) =
        Room.databaseBuilder(app,
                AppDatabase::class.java,
                "daily_accountant")
            // prepopulate the database after onCreate was called
            .addCallback(object : Callback() {
                override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                    super.onCreate(db)
                    // Do database operations through coroutine or any background thread
                    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
                        println("Caught during database creation --> $exception")
                    }

                    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch(handler) {
                        // Pre-populate database operations
                    }
                }
            })
            .build()
    }
}
```

And remove coroutineScope from from function parameter.